# WebdriverIo/ Typescript - How to call stored variables?

Tags: typescript, appium, return-value, webdriver-io, appium-android

I'm using WebdriverIO with Typescript to automate an Adnroid app.
Scenario:

1. Navigate to Training Page
2. Retrieve Session name (This value dynamically changes)

- So I want to store the retrieved session name in a varaible and assert it later

This is what I have done. But it's not working. So can someone pointout to me what I have done wrong here?

Thanks!!

***training.ts***

```
        import BaseAppScreen from "./base-app.screen";
    
    
    const SELECTORS = {
        Training_Card_Session_Name: (`~trainingItemTitle0`), // This is the one dynamically changing
    };
    
    export default class TrainingScreen extends BaseAppScreen{
        constructor() {
            super(); 
                $(SELECTORS.Training_Card_Session_Name).waitForDisplayed();
        }
    
        getSessionNameOfTrainingCard(): string{ 
            var trainingSessionName = $(SELECTORS.Training_Card_Session_Name).getText();
return trainingSessionName; // Here I want to retrive the getText value and store it in a variable to be called later.
        }
    
        
    }
```

***training.spec.ts***

```
    import TrainingScreen from '../screenobjects/training.screen';
    
    describe('Training Sessions', () => {
      let trainingScreen: TrainingScreen;

let trainingSessionName: string;
    
    
      beforeAll(() => {
        loginScreen = new LoginScreen();   
      });
    
      
      it(`Select a training Card`, () => {
        trainingScreen.getSessionNameOfTrainingCard();
        expect(trainingScreen.getSessionHeaderTitle()).toEqual(trainingSessionName);; // this is where I need to assert the previously stored text
      });
    
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done above is correct.

In ***training.spec.ts***, no need  to call the varaible inside toEqual assertion.
**trainingScreen.getSessionHeaderTitle()**, it self stores the value of returned text inside **trainingSessionName** variable. Therefore, can assert it to be equal to the  actual title name.

i.e.

```
expect(trainingScreen.getSessionHeaderTitle()).toEqual('TRAINING'); // The title TRAINING is a static value.
```